# 3D: Check point inside elliptical cone

Tags: math, 3d, pseudocode

I seem to have searched the whole internet trying to find an implementation of checking if a 3d `point` is within an elliptical cone defined by (`origin`, `length`, `horizontal angle`, `vertical angle`). Unfortunately without success as I only really found [one math solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/how-do-i-determine-if-a-point-is-interior-to-an-elliptical-cone) which I did not understand.

Now I am aware on how to use implement it using a normal cone:

```
inRange = magnitude(point - origin) <= length;
heading = normalized(point - origin);
return dot(forward, heading) >= cos(angle) && inRange;
```

However there the height detection is far too tall. I would really like to implement a more realistic vision cone for the AI for a game but this requires having the cone shaped more like a human field of view being more wide than tall.

Thanks a lot for any help:)

Comment: What you want is how to convert your definition of a cone to the standard cone coordinates shown in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5799/how-do-i-determine-if-a-point-is-interior-to-an-elliptical-cone. Then you can just follow their solution. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticCone.html for help with that.

Comment: You are missing the parameters for the major and minor radius of the cone base. Also the angle is not needed because you can always transform your point a coordinate system where the cone is along the `+z` axis.

Comment: And how is your horizontal and vertical angles defined?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help so far, horizontal and vertical angles are defined in radians of half the cone. So e.g. `angle = rad(90°)` means 180° degree forward-facing horizontal field of view

Comment: I asked the original question on the math exchange site you mentioned.  What about the question and the answer did you have difficulty understanding?

Comment: Hi, I am afraid not too much as my math seems to be a bit rusty. Especially how this translates into a real world example with a cone and a point to check somewhere in the world. It seems like I would need to transform them into a different coordinate system according to ja72 and I will need to dig deep into that stuff and hopefully figure it out. It seems like I am better understanding stuff from already working stuff than deriving it on my own:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a 3D elliptic cone, with base at `B=(x_B,y_B,z_B)`, height `h` along the cone axis `k=(k_x,k_y,j_z)`, major base radius `a`, minor base radius `b` and direction along the major axis `i=(i_x,i_y,i_z)` you need to find if a point `P=(x,y,z)` lies inside the cone. It is your choice on how to parametrize the major axis direction and I think your are trying to use [spherical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) with two angles.

Here are the steps to take:

1. Establish a coordinate system with origin on the base *B* and with the local *x* axis along your major axis `i`. The local *z* axis should be towards the tip along `k`. Finally the local *y* axis should be

   `j=cross(k,i)=(i_z*k_y-i_y*k_z, i_x*k_z-i_z*k_x, i_y*k_x-i_x*k_y)`
   `j=normalize(j)`

   Your `3×3` rotation matrix is defined by the columns `E=[i,j,k]`
2. Transform your point `P=(x,y,z)` into the local coordinates with

   `P2 = transpose(E)*(P-B) = (x2,y2,z2)`
3. Now establish how far along the axis of the cone is with `s=(h-z2)/h`  where `s=0` at the tip and `s=1` at the base.
4. If `s>1` or `s<0` then the point is outside
5. Otherwise if `s>0` you need to check that `(x2/(s*a))^2+(y2/(s*b))^2<=1` for the point to be inside.
6. If `s=0` then check that `x2=0` and `y2=0` for the point being exactly at the tip.

If you cannot do basic vector algebra, like cross products, 3D transformations and normalization that I suggest you have some reading to do before you can understand what is going on here.

Note:

```
//                  | i_x i_y i_z |
//  transpose(E) =  | j_x j_y j_z |
//                  | k_x k_y k_z |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to get this working over the next days and will mark you answer as the solution